# Image transition on mouse click

Tags: jquery, animation, transition

I am implementing a image gallery whereby if you click on an image thumbnail it shows you the bigger picture. However, I am trying to make it so that the image transitions from the one that is currently visible on the screen. The code which I currently have looks like this :

```
$('.box8').click(function(){
    $('#myMainPicture').animate({
        opacity:'toggle'}, 1000, 'linear', function() {
             $('#myMainPicture').attr("src", "thmb/pics/7.jpeg");
        });
    });

$('.box2').click(function(){
    $('#myMainPicture').animate({
        opacity:'toggle'}, 1000, 'linear', function() {
             $('#myMainPicture').attr("src", "thmb/pics/1.jpeg");
        });
    });

});
```

When I click on the element .box8 the current #myMainPicture picture element nicely disappears as dictated by the value of 'toggle' regardless of what is presently there on the screen. If I now click it again it will show me the picture defined in the src attribute.

The same applies to the .box2 element.

However, is there a way to animate this whole sequence so that the unloading of the old picture and loading of the new one happens in a single click as opposed to me having to press the mouse twice?

Many thanks,

vnayak

Answer (score 1):

Try split the code into reusable functions.

```
function animateTransition($image, newSrc){
    $image.animate({
       opacity:'toggle'}, 1000, 'linear', function() {
          if(newSrc){
             $image.attr("src", newSrc);
             animateTransition($image,null);
          }
    });
};
$('.box').on('click',function(){
    animateTransition($('#myMainPicture'),'thmb/pics/7.jpeg');
});
```

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for the code. I have implemented this and works perfectly fine. However, just to aide my understanding of what is happening here, would it be possible if you could explain to me the role if(newSRC){...} is playing in making this work.

Comment: No problem, the function has a recursive call. The reason for this is that the function toggles the opacity. So I want to call it twice, but only set the source once. So I call it with a source, it fades out, sets the new source, then calls the function again without a source. It fades back in, but because the new source (newSrc) is null, it won't call the function again. if(newSrc) is false if newSrc is null.

Answer (score 1):

you can write a jquery plugin for that, and apply the plugin on any images as you need

```
$.fn.animateTransition = function(callback,newsrc){
    var done = 0;
    var nb = this.length;
    function endAnim(){ if(++done === nb  && callback !== undefined) callback(); }
    this.each(function(){
        var $t = $(this);
        var src = newsrc;
        if(src === undefined || src === false)
            src = $t.data("src");
        if(src === undefined || src === "")
            return endAnim();
        $t.animate({opacity:0},1000,'linear',function(){
            $t.attr("src",src).animate({opacity:1},1000,'linear',endAnim);
        });
    });

    return this;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r043v/DhBvW/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both animations in one click like shown in this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var images = $('img.box'),
        main = $('#myMainPicture');
    main.prop("src", $(images[0]).attr('src')); // initialize main image
    images.click(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        main.stop().animate({
            opacity: 0 // fade out
        }, 1000, 'linear', function () {
            main.prop("src", src);
            main.animate({ opacity: 1 }); // fade in
        });
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/CyHtG/)